# One of Chebyshev's inequalities

Tags: analysis, inequality, polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

[image]

How can I prove that this polynomial has at least n+1 zeroes? I have no idea.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{P}_n$ here? What is $T_n$?

Comment: @Sean I would assume that $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the set of all polynomials of degree $n$. While $T_n$ is the Chebyshev Polynomial of degree $n$. However I am interested in what $\mathcal{P}_n^c$ is.

Comment: It is the set of all polynomials of degree n with complex coefficients.